# Question with wrong answer upvoted

Tags: support, answers, new-users, wrong-answers

I just asked my first question. It received one answer, which was wrong (i.e. the suggested solution did not work when actually run).  The answer has three upvotes.  I've made a comment on the answer and also updated the question to clarify what I'm asking about (see [Redrawing during drag-and-drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168649/redrawing-during-drag-and-drop)) and to indicate that the answer didn't work.

My question is: is there any way to indicate that the answer is wrong? I don't have enough rep to down vote yet and even then I think I could only down vote it once and the question would still be considered answered.  I'm a bit frustrated as the question is now kind of lost in the ether as it is considered answered, when in fact it isn't.

Comment: I filed my downvote for you, since you clearly mentioned the answer's method in your post and that it wasn't working as expected: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168649 for those wondering.

Answer (score 18):

You did right. You left a comment indicating that the answer didn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 9):

That's one reason why I'd like to see the separate counts for up- and downvotes for each answer and question. Sometimes the sum just isn't enough.

Comment: There's a userscript on stackapps that does this. http://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep

Answer (score 5):

Without having enough rep to vote down, about the only thing in your tool box is to leave a comment as you did stating that the offered solution did not fix your problem.  You can also use that as an opportunity to seek more information from the poster.

For example, the solution that was posted did not work, but maybe the posted solution could be tweaked slightly to work for you.  Leaving a comment could further the dialogue on the issue and pinpoint what the next viable option is.

Answer (score 4):

As long as you don't mark the answer as *the answer*, people will still see it in the list of questions and will probably have a look and see your comment (or maybe they see that the answer doesn't apply to your question) and add their own answer.

Granted, it might be more interesting for some to go to a question that has 0 answers compared to one that has several, but that shouldn't really matter.