# A flag towards an answer was declined, but the reason given seems to conflict with the flagging option description

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts, declined-flags

I flagged an answer with the option *very low quality*. According to this option description:

> This answer has severe formatting or content problems.

As far as I understand, the word *content* here means the technical side of the answer - the actual information given in the answer, and if it's technically incorrect, then the answer has *severe content problems*.

But I've got a flag declined with the reason *flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer*. This reason seems to conflict with the *very low quality* option description.

I'm not going to argue with this decision. I just want to understand the policy behind it in order to flag properly in future.

**Question: when is the question considered to have severe content problems?**

Comment: Probably when the poster's language is so poor that it is impossible to extract anything useful out of the post without making assumption?

Comment: Nope, that flag is purely about aesthetics, grammar, spelling etc..

Comment: key point in flag description is **"...unlikely to be salvageable through editing..."** - ie if you can not even imagine it being edited into something understandable, use the flag. Example: answer like "dfgdfgdfgd hjkhjk". In any other case, VLQ flag is quite risky - moderator may figure the way to "squeeze" some sense from flagged answer and decline VLQ.

Comment: If the problem with the answer is just that it's incorrect, i.e. with "the technical side of the answer", then it should be downvoted and not flagged - unless it's dangerously or maliciously evil (as described @Manish's answer below).

Comment: Comments are also helpful. Thanks, people!

Comment: Downvotes (and editing) are for wrong answers.  Flags are for things that require moderator intervention.  Think about it logistically for a moment.  Moderators couldn't possibly act on every wrong answer on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Jeff says:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95641/178438)

> Ask yourself this:
>
> > Would you be embarrassed to be associated with this post if it had your name on it?
>
> To me that is the essence of Very Low Quality. Not just bad but *embarrassingly* bad.

I *guess* a wrong answer is embarrassing. Then again, there's another part of the flag--the "unlikely to be salvageable" part.

[Jeff also says:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93606/178438)

> VLQ means the flagger thinks this post is beyond saving -- no amount of editing or polishing will turn this particular turd into gold. It is a call for a pooper-scooper.

Even wrong answers can be corrected--usually it's only a small part of them which is wrong. I think the answerer could have fixed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11304817/1198729) question(which is the one you're talking about, right?) on the basis of your comment (not sure, though).

---

[A bit more regarding wrong answers:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8879/178438) (though it talks about upvoted wrong answers, which can't be VLQ-flagged, anyway)

> If it is really, really wrong (as in dangerously wrong, like 'delete C:\NTLDR in order to improve computer performance'), flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: Brilliant! I think I got it now! And yes, the answer you reference is the one I'm talking about and I DO think it could be fixed by the author based on my comment (or at least removed). Thank you for the explanations!