# Why isn't there a possible duplicate banner on some questions?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I've seen several of these now, here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045661/css3-transitions-work-in-ie.

The question has 3 duplicate votes, and yet, no banner is shown for it ("This question may already have an answer here:"). Why is that? What determines whether a question displays the banner or not? (Or has it been removed and I'm simply not up-to-date?)

Comment: Probably a bug, indeed.

Comment: The behaviour has been changed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166527/stop-generating-possible-duplicate-comments/167980#167980

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [we're now only showing the pre-closure banner "This question may already have an answer here" to the question owner. No one else, not even mods, will see it until after the question is closed.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166427/automatic-insertion-of-dupe-banner-after-just-one-close-vote-is-vulnerable-to-ab/167987#167987)
>                                                                                                                           --Jarrod Tiberius Dixon

Basically, there was some valid concern that it got in the way / encouraged pile-on votes / lacked a good, similarly-prominent venue for disagreement when displayed to all potential close-voters. So we're back to comments for everyone *except* the asker, who gets a big (*hopefully* helpful) banner informing him that his answer is in another castle.

If you look at that question *now*, you should see the banner.

Comment: Interestingly, even this can be confusing, this time for the OP, who doesn't realise that not everybody can see what has transpired to be an invalid dup-banner: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267676/reference-to-an-unnamed-temporary-object-life-time?noredirect=1#comment21646082_15267676

Comment: Yeah, thought hey at least he responded. Nothing like getting a reply a day *after* you've closed a question wherein the OP finally explains why it's different...