# What to do when an answer is getting all of the focus but does not pertain to the question?

Tags: discussion, answers

I have a rather interesting bug or problem when using CSS shapes.

I have made an animation/css3 image and have a very odd pixelated border around the creatures eyes. I am not 100% sure what is causing it but I believe I may have the root of the problem.

When I first posted the question I had a link to a *similar yet minor* problem with an owl's eyes that I made with CSS months before. I happened to remember this problem when I was making my cat and thought it may be relevant to add to the question.

I really am not sure how the question got interpreted to be pertaining to the owl but someone provided an answer that does fix my owls situation.

The problem I have now is that everyone just keeps up-voting the answer but it clearly does not pertain to my question.

I feel that all the traffic see this nice question and looks as if it answers my question but after a lot of testing on my part I found out they are 2 different situations.

What does everyone think I should do about this? It isn't a bad answer or anything but it has nothing to do with the question I asked.

I also have added a lot of editing showing exactly what is happening and the answer still keeps getting up-votes.

I found this on meta, [How to deal with upvoted yet clearly wrong answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8879/how-to-deal-with-upvoted-yet-clearly-wrong-answers) which gave me some ideas but flagging the question for a mod in my eyes won't do the trick. I tried editing the answer to just include a line saying that this is a solution for the owl but does not pertain to the question and a mod denied the edit.

Here is my question about [Pixelated edge around a CSS Circle with overflow: hidden;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882283/pixelated-edge-around-a-css-circle-with-overflow-hidden).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I saw that question back when it was first posted, and I thought the same thing.

It simply seems as though the people voting don't understand the problem, thus they blindly upvote a seemingly good answer.

I would make a ***clearer*** comment on the answer, politely stating that's not the answer you were looking for, as it doesn't directly solve the problem. Based on your current comment on the answer, it seems as though it is a sufficient answer. I would also make that point clearer in the question itself, letting people know you are still looking for relevant answers.

Aside from that, you could always post a bounty on the question, and give an explanation within the bounty's summary. The attention you receive from the bounty would undoubtedly pay for itself.

Comment: Great post! I was about to post a bounty today but I was afraid that if no one could help then I just gave his answer the rep after the 7 days, I think it is. Is my question clear? I added images and everything trying to direct the focus away from that answer. I'll add another comment onto his answer though!

Comment: @JoshPowell To be honest, when I saw the question when you first posted it, it wasn't the clearest, and I couldn't really tell what the problem was. Nonetheless I thought it was a good question and upvoted it.. As for the bounty, i'd just go ahead and post one. It doesn't hurt, and like I said, it will pay for itself. Someone else will answer it when they see the bounty.

Comment: @JoshPowell On bounties: That answer would never be automatically awarded a bounty unless you accept it during the bounty period. If a bounty doesn't draw new answers, it will simply expire.

Comment: Alright, I'll post a bounty on it and I greatly appreciate your help! I do apologize for the unclairty of it when I first posted it, I was just very dumbfounded on how to word such an odd problem.

Comment: @animuson Thank you for clearing that up! I have never posted a bounty yet so that is good to know.

Comment: @JoshPowell It's all good. I might even answer it anyways.

Comment: Best of luck figuring that one out! My brain is so fried from trying to remove that darn pixelated edge.