# Handling myths in answers

Tags: discussion

Every now and then an answer is (fully or partially) based on a myth.

Myth, as in: there is literally zero evidence that supports it, yet many swear it is true

This of course leads to a certain amount of agreement and upvotes. Depending on the popularity of the myth and the amount of good counter-evidence, the amount of upvotes can be much higher than downvotes.

What can we do in such cases when the "myth believers" are in majority?

1. Write a comment that there is no evidence for the claim?
2. Edit the answer? (remove the false claim? or maybe leave it and note that it is a common misconception?)
3. Ask for supporting evidence? (this is basically same as 1)
4. Something else? (give up and let the myth grow, as SE is a quite popular source of information?)

An example of a myth, for the sake of argument:

> pigs can fly

Zero evidence for it (also, I hope, nobody really believes this).

I'm not giving an actual example for the reason to avoid responses like "hey, but that is actually true!"

I am referring to **technical discussions**, like on Super User, Server Fault and Stack Overflow.

Comment: definitely ask for links to documentation if it's a programming related question, or links to research documents if it's about anything science related

Comment: Depends on the site surely as most answers on [mythology](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/) would be based on myth surely and there would be no problem with that. The same applies to various other sites too.

Comment: @RobertLongson yes, I was thinking about technical sites, like superuser, serverfault and stackoverflow.com

Comment: Fly - verb: 2. "Move or be hurled quickly through the air."  Through my research, I have come to the conclusion that pigs are not a) massive enough to be unable to be thrown b) exist within an atmosphere.  Therefore, pigs can fly.

Comment: @DavidBalažic Especially for _technical (science)_ questions: 5. You can provide your own answer, proving the myths wrong. Your example is a bit bad, because from a physical POV pigs actually can fly, but not just on their own efforts.

Comment: How is this different from "Handling accepted answers that are wrong"?

Comment: @dustytrash No mention of _accepted answers_ in that question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ what about [highly upvoted wrong answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8879/how-to-deal-with-upvoted-yet-clearly-wrong-answers) then

Comment: @dustytrash _Highly upvoted_ is significantly different from _accepted_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ both are duplicates though. There exists a separate question for both.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Or how about https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8879/how-to-deal-with-upvoted-yet-clearly-wrong-answers ?  Seems to hit all the marks of this question.

Comment: @RageFoxx Technically yes!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Those other questions deal with "wrong answers" while I ask also about _partially_ wrong answers. Like a an answer that has 3 separate claims, where 2 are true and 1 is false. I did not stress that enough in the question . (writing good questions is as hard as writing a good answer, I guess)

Answer (score 7):

> 3. Ask for supporting evidence? (this is basically same as 1)

I like this approach, but don't ask the individual (who cares what they think?)---ask the community.  I.e., *if you have a question, **why not post a question?***

Just make sure ***the goal is not to prove someone wrong***, the goal is to learn something.

---

#### For example:

> This question is motivated by the following observation:
>
> > An example of a myth, for the sake of argument: pigs can fly
> > <sub>[David Balažic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342989/351283), 2020</sub>
>
> I'm not aware of any evidence to support the claim that "pigs can fly" is considered a myth.  I searched for [`pigs can fly myth`](https://cn.bing.com/search?q=pigs%20can%20fly%20myth) in Bing, but only found [this webpage](https://www.weknowtheanswer.com/q/can-pigs-fly-or-is-that-a-myth) which appears unreliable.
>
> **Question**: Is "pigs can fly" considered a myth?

Comment: I'm not sure a question of this form would "fly" [on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour): "Don't ask about... Requests for lists of things, polls, opinions, discussions, etc."

Comment: @NathanReinstateMonicaArthur The answer doesn't say to post it on Stackoverflow. That question would okay on another SE site

Comment: I [did](https://superuser.com/questions/1525880/hdd-certain-unrecoverable-read-failure-ure-after-12tb-read-true-or-false) exactly this and the question was closed in 30 minutes.

Comment: That's very odd in my opinion, but I don't use Super User.

Answer (score 7):

[Does Linux perform "opportunistic swapping", or is it a myth?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/533739/does-linux-perform-opportunistic-swapping-or-is-it-a-myth/?noredirect=1)

I tried phrasing it as a dedicated question.  Define my terms, ask if it is true or false, *and ask for evidence*.

In other words, create a reference which people can point to (and vote on, either way).

I was happy with my definition, and the technical details in my answer.

I'm not so happy with the length of my Q&A :-).  I think part of the challenge is knowing where to stop arguing.  Some people just won't let go of a myth, or will say you're misinterpreting how people are talking about the myth.  Don't assume you can convince everyone if you just keep adding more details.

That said, the point was to pin down the myth.  I had to spend *some* time characterising the claims...  I think I felt obliged to quote at least one example.  If I had linked to a specific SE answer, and they deleted it because I convinced them, then it would have broken my question.

I also tried commenting on some of the mythical answers.  I didn't see much good come from it.  Comments are hard.

Comment: I [did](https://superuser.com/questions/1525880/hdd-certain-unrecoverable-read-failure-ure-after-12tb-read-true-or-false) exactly this and the question was closed in 30 minutes.